# Website without server that relies on API to retrieve and save data... static or dynamic?

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, static

I just read the following.

> ... your web app can be considered static. Some examples of this type of
>   web application are a simple personal home page, an online games
>   portal that doesn’t save data to the server on which it is hosted, or
>   an AngularJS app that performs multiple calls to a RESTful API
>   provided by another service.

So if a website is based purely on angular, does not have any server code and solely depends on API calling to retrieve and save data, will it be considered static or dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic website means we can change the site's content without modify the source code. For your website, if it is showing data from a REST API which means it is depending on a server somewhere then it is a dynamic website.